# In which table the schema's are stored?

Tags: oracle

Hello I am using Oracle 11g. I want to know in which table information about the schemas created is stored ?

Comment: What kind of informations do you need? A list of tables, objects, grants, tablespace, ...?

Answer (score 0):

You can find information about the users (owners of the schemas) from dba_users.
A more general useful view would be the dba_objects one.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but this query will return the name of the schemas with any object

*select distinct owner from dba_objects*